# Creating objects in ASP.NET Core 6 with EF Core, when they contain foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm a beginner with .NET and I'm having a hard time understanding how to create objects with foreign keys.

Let's say I have this `Localitate` entity (which vaguely translates to city) which contains a FK to `Judet` (county):

```
namespace xx.DataLayer.Entities
{
    public class Localitate : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        public string Nume { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JudetID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Judet Judet { get; set; }

        public Localitate() { }
    }
}
```

Here's how my request looks:

```
public class LocalitateRequest
{
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public int JudetID { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a `Localitate` object, how should I do it? Do I need to fill the navigation property too, or is the `int JudetID` enough?

If it is enough, I'm encountering another problem - if I insert a `JudetID` that doesn't exist, I don't get any error (and I think I should, my DB would do that if I would be doing an insert statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a Localitate object, how should I do it? Do I need to fill the navigation property too, or is the int JudetID enough?

You can fill in the foreign ID if you wish, but this is very non-intuitive. Think about it, you know what entity you want to link your object to by name, right? So a more natural way of building your object would be like:

```
context.Localitati.Add(new()
{
    Nume = "meep",
    Judet = context.Judete.First(w => w.Nume = "moop")
});
```

To avoid repeated lookups, you can use dictionaries to memoize objects. Either way, you need to fill in either the ID or the foreign entity's ID field (which can be done by selecting it out).

> if I insert a JudetID that doesn't exist, I don't get any error

Sure, because that's not a foreign key. Either declare it as such with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute, or use the correct naming convention: `JudetId`.

Comment: Also, avoid using foreign names in projects that are maintained by multiple people, we live in a globalized world. You might say that you don't intend to, but you literally did just now, and I had to type them. It was made worse by the fact that you didn't even type them correctly, it's `Județ`.

Comment: It's a small project that will only be used by me, don't worry :) about Judet vs Județ, the second choice is the "literal" one, but in my country we write in the second way only in formal documents. (because it is a bit of an overkill)

Comment: Now, ASP.Net core related - I'm actually using an automapper which maps from LocalitateRequest.JudetId to Localitate.JudetId. If I'd like to fill the navigation property, how would I do it?

Comment: Also, I thought the naming convention is JudetID for example, not JudetId. Thanks for pointing that out to me :)

Comment: If you know the ID, then by all means, use the ID. I’d question where you get your ID from, it sounds like sql injection to me, but that’s up to you and your security team to look into.